# Widget buttons not working after phone call

Tags: android

I am working on a android home widget. 
When i start a call intent with a button click (that is in an activity that i started with a click on a widget's button), 
after the call ends, 
the widget's buttons don't work.

When i click the buttons the background of buttons changes, 
so the widget doesn't crashes, it works but don't loads the intents i think. And there is no Log record about this issue.

I start the phone call like this:

```
Intent callIntent=new Intent();
        callIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

then finish the activity. If i don't finish the activity again it works, but i need to finish the activity.

Edit:

Following issue is happening randomly, after phone call sometimes screen goes black. When i press home button it opens and widget buttons work but takes action after 4-5 second i press, but sometimes screen doesn't go black and the widget buttons don't work.

Edit:

LogCat filled with version errors except last ones. But it is under control. I control version with this:
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
But it still records these logs. But app works fine.

Log

```
    04-23 23:18:05.715: I/dalvikvm(4300): Could not find method android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged, referenced from method org.MyApp.AWidget.AWidgetProvider.UpdateWidget
04-23 23:18:05.715: W/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 123: Landroid/appwidget/AppWidgetManager;.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged ([II)V
04-23 23:18:05.715: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002a
04-23 23:18:05.723: I/dalvikvm(4300): Could not find method android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged, referenced from method org.MyApp.AWidget.AWidgetProvider.onReceive
04-23 23:18:05.723: W/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 123: Landroid/appwidget/AppWidgetManager;.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged ([II)V
04-23 23:18:05.723: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x006e
04-23 23:18:05.727: I/dalvikvm(4300): Could not find method android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged, referenced from method org.MyApp.AWidget.AWidgetProvider.onUpdate
04-23 23:18:05.727: W/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 123: Landroid/appwidget/AppWidgetManager;.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged ([II)V
04-23 23:18:05.727: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0019
04-23 23:18:05.731: W/dalvikvm(4300): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/AWidgetService; (487)
04-23 23:18:05.731: W/dalvikvm(4300): Link of class 'Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/AWidgetService;' failed
04-23 23:18:05.731: E/dalvikvm(4300): Could not find class 'org.MyApp.AWidget.AWidgetService', referenced from method org.MyApp.AWidget.AWidgetProvider.onUpdate
04-23 23:18:05.731: W/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 612 (Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/AWidgetService;) in Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/AWidgetProvider;
04-23 23:18:05.731: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x01ec
04-23 23:18:05.731: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: dead code 0x01ee-025e in Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/AWidgetProvider;.onUpdate (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/appwidget/AppWidgetManager;[I)V
04-23 23:18:08.938: E/dalvikvm(4300): Could not find class 'android.widget.PopupMenu', referenced from method org.MyApp.AWidget.SetRemind.showPopupMenu
04-23 23:18:08.938: W/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 482 (Landroid/widget/PopupMenu;) in Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/SetRemind;
04-23 23:18:08.938: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
04-23 23:18:08.941: D/dalvikvm(4300): VFY: dead code 0x0002-001d in Lorg/MyApp/AWidget/SetRemind;.showPopupMenu (Landroid/view/View;)V
04-23 23:18:09.184: D/dalvikvm(4300): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 92K, 47% free 2874K/5379K, external 2003K/2108K, paused 172ms
04-23 23:18:09.238: D/dalvikvm(4300): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 18K, 47% free 2867K/5379K, external 2591K/2934K, paused 22ms
04-23 23:18:09.293: D/dalvikvm(4300): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 47% free 2869K/5379K, external 3134K/3613K, paused 26ms
04-23 23:18:09.469: D/dalvikvm(4300): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 28K, 46% free 2932K/5379K, external 4281K/4292K, paused 23ms
04-23 23:18:10.754: D/dalvikvm(4300): GC_EXPLICIT freed 100K, 43% free 3394K/5895K, external 4445K/5380K, paused 26ms
```

I cleared all of the version Errors by moving the methods to another class. But still the same, this time there are more GC errors

Newest LOG:

```
04-24 00:41:03.345: D/dalvikvm(6003): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 102K, 47% free 2878K/5379K, external 2003K/2108K, paused 31ms
04-24 00:41:03.396: D/dalvikvm(6003): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 26K, 47% free 2862K/5379K, external 2591K/2934K, paused 26ms
04-24 00:41:03.450: D/dalvikvm(6003): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 47% free 2865K/5379K, external 3134K/3613K, paused 21ms
04-24 00:41:03.708: D/dalvikvm(6003): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 27K, 46% free 2930K/5379K, external 4281K/4292K, paused 61ms
04-24 00:41:05.341: D/dalvikvm(6003): GC_EXPLICIT freed 108K, 43% free 3397K/5895K, external 4445K/5380K, paused 29ms
04-24 00:41:32.685: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 87K, 47% free 2866K/5379K, external 2003K/2108K, paused 25ms
04-24 00:41:32.735: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 18K, 47% free 2858K/5379K, external 2591K/2934K, paused 21ms
04-24 00:41:32.774: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 47% free 2861K/5379K, external 3134K/3613K, paused 19ms
04-24 00:41:33.024: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 30K, 46% free 2927K/5379K, external 4281K/4292K, paused 31ms
04-24 00:41:34.103: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXPLICIT freed 104K, 43% free 3393K/5895K, external 4445K/5380K, paused 24ms
04-24 00:41:35.071: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXPLICIT freed 425K, 46% free 3406K/6279K, external 4068K/5081K, paused 25ms
04-24 00:41:35.923: D/dalvikvm(6316): GC_EXPLICIT freed 417K, 46% free 3413K/6279K, external 4068K/5081K, paused 27ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null);
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
 callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: thanks but it is the same as before. Following thing is happening randomly, after phone call sometimes screen goes black. When i press home button it opens and widget buttons work but takes action after 4-5 second i press, but sometimes screen doesn't go black and the widget buttons don't work.

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` should do the trick, but have a look at my call widget here https://bitbucket.org/jholetzeck/minicallwidget-android/src/8e6c325f299775674ec530abb64ee39302cf89ff/src/de/holetzeck/minicallwidget/MiniCallWidget.java?at=default

Comment: But you directly start the call from a click on widget, in my case, i start call from an activity. Maybe this is why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: How do you start your activity from the widget? You should also use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` then!

Comment: Intent a=new Intent();
       a.setClass(mContext,SeeRemind.class);
   a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       mContext.startActivity(a); this is how i start it

Comment: Ok, different guess. As it takes 4-5 sec before your widget works again have a look at logcat if your app maybe uses lots of resources (e.g. RAM, long running GC, ...) so home screen has to load again.

Comment: So it seems that your problem is definitely in your app, just see the time stamps! You are using lots of API calls which doesn't fit to your run time version, so the verifier must remove these calls from your class file. Please post some relevant part from your app. Btw: have a look at [lazy class loading](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html)

Comment: I cleared all of the version Errors by moving the methods to another class. But still the same, this time there are more GC errors ( Not errors actually log records )